# How to get adsense ads to use context hints and refresh on ajax site

Tags: ajax, adsense, google-dfp

This may really be two separate questions, except that there may be some dependency between the two solutions.

What I have is an ajax site, and I would like to show google adsense ads that are relevant to the search terms that people type in on my site.

So if someone searches for 'cheese' on my site, I want to refresh the google adsense ad AND sent it the hint 'cheese', so that it shows results relevant to cheese, and I want to do this without refreshing my page ie do it through ajax.

I'm signed up to adsense, and can get regular ads to show. I'm also signed up to google dfp and can get those ads to show. I've been googling for an hour and made no progress in figuring out what to do next. Very grateful for any help anyone can offer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about adsense sorry but as far as DFP is concerned you should be able to work out everything you need to do from the docs here: http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1650154&expand=pubservice_details#refresh

You probably need to look at the clearTargeting, setTargeting and refresh methods.